# ta4j RSI indicator value does not match with TradingView

Tags: java, technical-indicator, rsi

I want to get live RSI data continuously. What I do is;

Get candlestick values from Binance API, fill the BarSeries with Bars using Binance response.

I am using [ta4j](https://github.com/mdeverdelhan/ta4j-origins) Java library

When I compare my value to TradingView, it does not match.

I have used SMA indicator instead of default MMA indicator when initializing RSIIndicator.

Here is my screenshots including code:

https://ibb.co/WFTx2N5

https://ibb.co/0mzF8Lv

https://imgbb.com/zXJqXjs

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be solved if you use more values ​​to load the `RSI`, in the following link you can see more about this.

https://github.com/ta4j/ta4j/issues/185

---

It could also be because you are using a different indicator in TradingView and in `Ta4j` as happened to the user of this question

[calculation of RSI(Relative Strength Index) Using ta4j java library is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607673/calculation-of-rsirelative-strength-index-using-ta4j-java-library-is-incorrect)